# How to save TensorRT graph generated from frozen inference graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I using the below script to convert my frozen_inference_graph into a TensorRT optimized one:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # First deserialize your frozen graph:
    with tf.gfile.GFile('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        frozen_graph = tf.GraphDef()
        frozen_graph.ParseFromString(f.read())
    # Now you can create a TensorRT inference graph from your
    # frozen graph:
    converter = trt.TrtGraphConverter(
        input_graph_def=frozen_graph,
        nodes_blacklist=['outputs/Softmax']) #output nodes
    trt_graph = converter.convert()
    # Import the TensorRT graph into a new graph and run:
    output_node = tf.import_graph_def(
        trt_graph,
        return_elements=['outputs/Softmax'])
    sess.run(output_node)
```

My question is how can I save this optimized graph to disk so I can use it to run inference?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can just add those two lines:

```html
saved_model_dir_trt = "./tensorrt_model.trt"
converter.save(saved_model_dir_trt)
```